# mongodb keeps data in two places

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, server

My remote server is `ubuntu 14.04` and I have `mongodb` installed there.  But when I tried to restore my `DataBase` using `mongorestore` I noticed the disk space in the following two places have reduced significantly.

```
/var/lib/mongodb

/data/db
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: are the contents of the 2 folders the same or different?

Comment: I can think of one possibility is that when you have `journal` on, the journal files by default goes into `/var/lib/mongodb/journal`. See if there's a journal between this folder and `/data/db`

Comment: all the file size is the same.  But now sure if the contents are exactly the same or what.

Comment: yes there is a /var/lib/mongodb/journal folder but it has only 1mb of data.  most of the files lies outside of this folder

Comment: Can you say exactly how you run mongorestore?

Comment: It looks very much like your MongoDB version is ( or was ) a 2.x series. In the 3.X series you need a running daemon in order to use `mongorestore` but in earlier versions you could restore a non-running database. But unless stated otherwise with the [`--dbpath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--dbpath) option dictates where the data is restored to. Modern 3.X releases need the daemon running and the similar `--dbpath` tells where the data is. In the latter case, you likely started the daemon without that option and ended up with the default `/data` path.

Comment: why don't you check the currently running mongod process and see which data directory it's using?  You can also look at timestamps on the files in these two directories.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have installed mongo with Ubuntu's APT.

If you simply start the mongod server in a terminal with either `nohup` or simply keep it running in a different terminal, it assumes the default db path as `/data/db/` and the default logging directory as `/var/log/mongo`.

You might have started `mongod` with a command like

```
./bin/mongod
```

which takes the default data and logging directory.

`mongorestore` works according to the configuration of the `mongod` server. This is the reason why you see a surge in space consumption of those directories after you run `mongorestore`.

The correct way to start the `mongod` server is with the following command

```
sudo service mongod start
```

If you don't want to start/stop as a service, you could also instruct the `mongod` to correctly use the conf file with the following command

```
./bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Your `mongod` conf file is located at `/etc/mongod.conf`. Please change the `dbpath` and `logpath` accordingly.

Comment: reason why I am not starting as a service is because I have authentication enabled.  So I execute the command `mongod --auth`.  Also for the current setting can you tell which part is the true db mongo is getting data from?

Comment: also can I delete any of the two folders and make sure the original mongo db can run without a problem?

Comment: You can certainly delete one of the directories, PROVIDED you know which data directory and logging directory you started `mongod` with ?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, I can deduce the question in to two parts:

1. why did the file system size reduce after mongorestore
2. why does mongodb store data in two locations?

*Answer for first Q:*

Mongorestore just collects the data, but the filesystem size can be different than the actual data size. Mogodb is designed to be in that fashion, it will allocate more space than the actual data size in DB. There is a detailed explanation in the mongodb website refer this section in [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/)

> **Why are the files in my data directory larger than the data in my
>   database?**
>
> The data files in your data directory, which is the /data/db directory
>   in default configurations, might be larger than the data set inserted
>   into the database. Consider the following possible causes:

*Second Q:*

Refer to `bsd` response, seems a possible case.

Comment: thanks ya db is also much larger than mongorestore bson files in my case